# How to check that test throws exception in app using Xcode UITest

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I'm trying to write UI test in Xcode to be able to know if my code causes UITableView to crash during refreshing on pull to refresh.

My test looks like this:

```
func testPullToRefresh_shouldNotCrash() throws {
    do {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        
        let tableView = app.tables.firstMatch
        try pullToRefresh(from: tableView)
    } catch {
        XCTFail("Crashed")
    }
}
```

Tried also doing:

```
    func testPullToRefresh_shouldNotCrash() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    
    let tableView = app.tables.firstMatch
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try pullToRefresh(from: tableView))
}
```

When I run test, app does crash, I see the exception in Xcode but after all test is succeeded

I tried writing sample project but it isn't working anyway

Sample code:

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private var dataSource = DataSource()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = dataSource
        tableView.delegate = dataSource
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
    
    @objc func refreshData() throws {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)], with: .automatic)
            self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
}
```

DataSource:

```
import UIKit

class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    var data = ["Cell 1", "Cell 2", "Cell 3", "Cell 4", "Cell 5"]
    
    // UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    // UITableViewDelegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Test:

```
import XCTest

final class ExceptionTestsUITests: XCTestCase {

    func testPullToRefresh_shouldNotCrash() throws {
        do {
            let app = XCUIApplication()
            app.launch()
            
            let tableView = app.tables.firstMatch
            try pullToRefresh(from: tableView)
        } catch {
            XCTFail("Crashed")
        }
    }
    
    func pullToRefresh(from element: XCUIElement) throws {
        let startPosition = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        let endPosition = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 500)
        let start = element.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)).withOffset(CGVector(dx: startPosition.x, dy: startPosition.y))
        let finish = element.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)).withOffset(CGVector(dx: endPosition.x, dy: endPosition.y))
        start.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: finish)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: The `catch` blocks don't catch Objective-C exceptions, they catch Swift errors that are thrown using the `throw` keyword. Plus, the UI test is a different process, so if the app under test crashes, the test will fail anyway.

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing you should be testing with a unit test, not a ui test